# How to use angularJs code inside of JSP file?

Tags: angularjs, eclipse, html, jsp, angularjs-directive

I am trying adding angular code inside of .jsp file but getting some error like :
**"Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Start tag of element 
    - Undefined attribute name 
     (ng-app)."**

So can anyone help how to proceed with it !

Comment: share code to understand

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
   app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope){
    $scope.myData="stackOverflow";
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <h1>{{myData}}</h1>
  </div> 
 </body>
</html>`

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following code to your JSP/Html file to user angular code:

```
 <script>
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

 myApp.controller('anyController', function ($scope, $http)
 {
    // Write your angular code here

 });
 </script>
```

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/npm/node_modules//@progress/kendo-theme-default/dist/all.css" />

Answer (score 0):

Probably those errors are just from the html validator and can be ignored. I never used it but you could try a plugin like this https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse